# Import module exported by webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I have created a JS file by using webpack export.

I am trying to import main.JS file in react app.

I am not able to import JS file created by webpack. Is this way of importing JS is the right approach in react?

I have tried all the library target option in webpack but none of the target type didnt work

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill",'./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    libraryExport: 'default',
    library: 'API'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

main.js export file structure:

```
exports.API=function(t){..}).default;
```

react app:

```
import {API} from "./main.js";
```

I want to use the webpack export file in react app?

Comment: Issue got resolved by using "window.API()"